# spark (pyspark) UnicodeEncodeError on yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, unicode, pyspark

I'm running some simple pyspark code that tries to print a "shrug" at the end. I'm running pyspark with Yarn and when I run my code in client mode everything works properly. When I run my code in cluster mode (`--deploy-mode cluster`) then I get a `UnicodeEncodeError` error.

Obviously I can not print the "shrug" but I feel like I'm missing something major here. **Should I be worried my code isn't handling unicode properly?**

**Attempted solution:**

I've set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3`.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Spark Imports
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("myApp")\
        .getOrCreate()

    ...
    print("¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
```

- *No error:* `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn  myApp.py`
- *Throws error:* `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode clustersparkcluster myApp.py`

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "myApp.py", line 435, in <module>
        print("\xaf\_(\u30c4)_/\xaf")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xaf' in position 46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Settings:**

I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias sparkclient="/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/bin/spark-submit --master yarn 
alias sparkcluster="/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 6g 
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV=PYTHONHASHSEED=0
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of pyspark whatsoever, but my guess is that it launches a number of subprocesses, and the env vars somehow aren't inherited or get overridden. When you `print()` something, the content is written with `sys.stdout`, the encoding of which is set through env vars like `PYTHONIOENCODING`. One way to avoid this environment-dependent behaviour is by doing the encoding yourself and writing to the underlying binary STDOUT stream: `sys.stdout.buffer.write("¯\_(ツ)_/¯".encode("utf8"))`

Comment: I realize there are hacks for this but I'm more concerned that I'm missing a larger issue and that my code isn't handling unicode in the way I'm expecting it to.

Comment: Whenever you use `print()`, you render the execution of your code platform-dependent, especially if the printed contents are non-ASCII. If you want more predictable behaviour, the only thing you can do from within Python is using the binary STDOUT buffer. I'm not sure this qualifies as a hack, but I agree that the code looks less elegant than with just `print(...)`.